# A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: fwrite(): 39 is not a valid stream resource

Tags: php, codeigniter, filesystems

Below is the code where I attempt to write results from database into a text file. But I keep getting the error message as above. I suppose this has something do with syntax yet I am not able to resolve it. Please share yours on how to figure it out.

```
     public function createfile(){

        $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('crd_article_desc');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result=$query->result_array();         

    $txt ='';
    $counter = 1;                       
    foreach($result as $results){

    $vp_string = trim($results['article_title']);

    $vp_string = html_entity_decode($vp_string);

    $vp_string = strip_tags($vp_string);

    $vp_string = strtolower($vp_string);

    $vp_string = preg_replace('~[^ a-z0-9_.]~', ' ', $vp_string);

    $vp_string = preg_replace('~ ~', '-', $vp_string);

    $vp_string = preg_replace('~-+~', '-', $vp_string);

    $new_friendly_url = $vp_string; 
    echo $results['article_title'];
    $looptxt = $results['article_id']."-".$new_friendly_url."\n";

    $txt=$txt.$looptxt;

    fwrite($myfile,$txt);
    fclose($myfile);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but in your code

```
foreach($result as $results){

    [...]
    $txt=$txt.$looptxt;

    fwrite($myfile,$txt);
    fclose($myfile);
}
```

it seems to me as if you are closing the file within the loop. In the second iteration of the loop you are trying to write to the file you just closed, which - of course - fails.

I think to fix this you'll have to close the loop just before the `fwrite`

```
foreach($result as $results){

    [...]
    $txt=$txt.$looptxt;
    }

    fwrite($myfile,$txt);
    fclose($myfile);
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help